# Apply custom style to a TransitionFrame in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, styles, transition

I want my `TransitionFrame`'s backgound to be white, other then black, as is by default.

I have added the following style declaration on the PhoneApplicationPage:

```
<Style TargetType="toolkit:TransitionFrame">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

How do I force the transition frame to use my style, that is defined in each page separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App.xaml.cs, in InitializePhoneApplication:

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
RootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

In the same way, if you have more properties, and want to use a style, you could probably use

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
RootFrame.Style = (Style) Current.Resources["MyStyle"];
```

Edit: Might've misread the question, if you want a custom style per page (I don't judge :p) then you can access the rootframe by adding static to your RootFrame declaration:

```
public static TransitionFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }
```

and elsewhere, simply using `App.RootFrame.<property>`